# UIImageView resizes after selecting row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

UIImageView frame resizes after i select any row in a table view. It looks like this:

[image]

"Clip subviews" turned on.
Reloading tableView on viewWillAppear doesn't work.
All size-based operations happens in storyboard.

Comment: show your code.. are you setting size from code?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya all size-based operations are in storyboard.

Comment: what is in your didSelectRow method? name of your image view is imageView?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Name is "thumbnailImageView".  [didSelectRow method image](http://cl.ly/2f040o0F292f/Image%202016-02-26%20at%206.22.34%20PM.png)

Comment: And are you setting image to cell.thumbnailImageView or cell.ImageView?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya first one.

Comment: try to reload your table view in viewWillappear method

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya nope, doesn't work.

Comment: Please Provide your code so we can check and resolve your issue

Comment: try to reload ur table on View will apear

Comment: without a single piece of code it is hard to understand, but you can try [cell layoutIfNeeded] just before return cell; in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you created custom UITableViewCell and named outlet to UIImageView as '**imageView**'? UITableViewCell also has property with the same name and it causes collision. I had the same issue and renaming resolved it!